# Re-usable PDO query function to multidimansional array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I'm trying to build a re-usable function to multidimansional array for every tablename i put in.
Like most i start mine tables whit ID and want to start the array whit that id, so not start whit 0 :) . `foneticly--> $my_array[id]["email"]`

So to build it i thought "what do i need" and found : `$count_colum`, `$total_row` an ofcource the data itself.

I know how to build a array, but i dont know how to build a "variable" array.
I also know i cant use PHP inside a array :) (whish would help iff you tell me)
`$my_array = array( $row['id'] for ($i = 0; $i < $count_colum; $i++){...}`
I also hope somebody knows what i mean :) I'm a little bit new to this all ;)

This is what i get this far:

```
function make_MDA($tablename)
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host='localhost';dbname='dbname', 'usr','pas'");
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `".$tablename."`"); 
    $query->execute();

    $count_colum = $query->columnCount();
    $result = $query->fetchAll();
    $total_row = count($result);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count_colum; $i++) 
    {
        $meta = $query->getColumnMeta($i);
        $column[] = $meta['name'];
    }
    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        $my_array = array( $row['id'] //this is where I'm stuck
    }
//        echo $column[3];
//        echo $total_row;
//        echo $count_colum;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, don't overcomplicate things:

```
function make_MDA($tablename)
{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host='localhost';dbname='dbname', 'usr','pas'");
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `".$tablename."`"); 
    $query->execute();

    $result = $query->fetchAll();

    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $my_array[$id] = $row; 
    }

    return $my_array;
}
```

I would make the connection to the database `$dbh` once outside this function.

Comment: thnx, this totaly worked.... +1 4 U :)
btw why would you do the $dbh once outside this function?

Comment: So you can reuse the connection multiple times with this function for different database tables. Similar reason as to why you make functions. You need to know that building a database connection is a costly process. It takes time and resources.